# InflateException:Couldn't resolve menu item onClick on Class

Tags: android

I am getting an error:  `android.view.InflateException: Couldn't resolve menu item onClick handler onClickEnterData in class com.android.timesheet.NewProjects`.

I had used the onClick operation in menu item.I am mention the error line in NewProjects.java

**StackTrace:**

```
12-15 04:45:51.845: E/AndroidRuntime(2777): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-15 04:45:51.845: E/AndroidRuntime(2777): Process: com.android.timesheet, PID: 2777
12-15 04:45:51.845: E/AndroidRuntime(2777): android.view.InflateException: Couldn't resolve menu item onClick handler onClickEnterData in class com.android.timesheet.NewProjects
12-15 04:45:51.845: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at android.view.MenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.<init>(MenuInflater.java:217)
12-15 04:45:51.845: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at android.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.setItem(MenuInflater.java:417)
12-15 04:45:51.845: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at android.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.addItem(MenuInflater.java:451)
12-15 04:45:51.845: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at android.view.MenuInflater.parseMenu(MenuInflater.java:188)
12-15 04:45:51.845: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at android.view.MenuInflater.inflate(MenuInflater.java:110)
12-15 04:45:51.845: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at com.android.timesheet.NewProjects.onCreateOptionsMenu(NewProjects.java:82)
12-15 04:45:51.845: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2538)
12-15 04:45:51.845: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:436)
12-15 04:45:51.845: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:800)
12-15 04:45:51.845: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:221)
12-15 04:45:51.845: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
12-15 04:45:51.845: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
12-15 04:45:51.845: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
12-15 04:45:51.845: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
12-15 04:45:51.845: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-15 04:45:51.845: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-15 04:45:51.845: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-15 04:45:51.845: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
12-15 04:45:51.845: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-15 04:45:51.845: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-15 04:45:51.845: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
12-15 04:45:51.845: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
12-15 04:45:51.845: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-15 04:45:51.845: E/AndroidRuntime(2777): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: onClickEnterData [interface android.view.MenuItem]
12-15 04:45:51.845: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:472)
12-15 04:45:51.845: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:857)
12-15 04:45:51.845: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     at android.view.MenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.<init>(MenuInflater.java:215)
12-15 04:45:51.845: E/AndroidRuntime(2777):     ... 22 more
```

**main.xml:**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_add_alarm"
        android:title="@string/add_task"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:onClick="onClickEnterData"
        />

</menu>
```

**NewProjects.java:**

```
public void onClickEnterData(View btnAdd) {

    startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, EnterDataActivity.class),
            ENTER_DATA_REQUEST_CODE);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);  ----->82nd Error line
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
//  case R.id.add:
//      Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActionBarButton.class);
        // intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
        // Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
//      startActivity(intent);
//      return true;

      case android.R.id.home: 
            onBackPressed();
            return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**new_project.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#A6CAED"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_data"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The signature of `onClickEnterData` is wrong. It has to be

```
public void onClickEnterData(MenuItem item)
```

From the documentation

> Tip: Android 3.0 adds the ability for you to define the on-click
>   behavior for a menu item in XML, using the android:onClick attribute.
>   The value for the attribute must be the name of a method defined by
>   the activity using the menu. The method must be public and accept a
>   single MenuItem parameter—when the system calls this method, it passes
>   the menu item selected. For more information and an example, see the
>   Menu Resource document.

Comment: very much thank you for your nice explanation and Corrected the error.Will Accept your answer after 8 minutes, seems to be some error here.